# Aggregate by value in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

How can I group the values present in **el1** by the first element of the sub-list which is **Germany** as shown below.

Input

```
from collections import defaultdict

el = [('GPE', 'Germany', 10, 12, 1.0), ('GPE', 'Germany', 23, 25, 1.0), ('GPE', 'Germany', 81, 83, 1.0),
 ('GPE', 'Germany', 163, 165, 1.0), ('GPE', 'Brazil', 219, 221, 1.0), ('GPE', 'Brazil', 260, 262, 1.0),
 ('CARDINAL', 'at least 3000', 26, 29, 1.0), ('CARDINAL', '124', 94, 95, 1.0)]


el1 = defaultdict(list)

for en,c,s,e,sf in el:
    el1[en].append((c,(s,e,sf)))

el1.items()
```

el1.items()

```
dict_items([('GPE', [('Germany', (10, 12, 1.0)), ('Germany', (23, 25, 1.0)), ('Germany', (81, 83, 1.0)), ('Germany', (163, 165, 1.0)), ('Brazil', (219, 221, 1.0)), ('Brazil', (260, 262, 1.0))]), ('CARDINAL', [('at least 3000', (26, 29, 1.0)), ('124', (94, 95, 1.0))])])
```

Code that I tried for grouping

```
import itertools
key_func = lambda x: x[0]

for i in list(el1.items()):
    for j in i[1]:    
        for key, group in itertools.groupby(j, key_func):
            print(key, list(group))
```

output

```
G ['Germany']
10 [(10, 12, 1.0)]
G ['Germany']
23 [(23, 25, 1.0)]
G ['Germany']
81 [(81, 83, 1.0)]
G ['Germany']
```

Expected output

```
 [('GPE', [('Germany', [(10, 12, 1.0), (23, 25, 1.0), (81, 83, 1.0), (163, 165, 1.0)]),
          ('Brazil', [(219, 221, 1.0), (260, 262, 1.0)])]), 
 ('CARDINAL', [('at least 3000', [(26, 29, 1.0)]), 
               ('124', [(94, 95, 1.0)])])]
```

Comment: Can you please show what's you've tried. and what's going wrong?

Comment: @DanielHao I have added the code and intermediate results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that problem is clearer. Here is a method using panda dataframe.groupby():

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for k,v in pd.DataFrame(el, columns = ['t','c','v1','v2','v3']).groupby(['t','c']):
    d[k[0]].append((k[1], [tuple(arr[2:]) for arr in v.to_dict(orient='split')['data']]))
```

#### Output

```
defaultdict(list,
        {'CARDINAL': [('124', [(94, 95, 1.0)]),
          ('at least 3000', [(26, 29, 1.0)])],
         'GPE': [('Brazil', [(219, 221, 1.0), (260, 262, 1.0)]),
          ('Germany',
           [(10, 12, 1.0),
            (23, 25, 1.0),
            (81, 83, 1.0),
            (163, 165, 1.0)])]})
```

#### OLD ANSWER

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list) 
d['GPE'].append(dict(text = 'Germany', offset = [(10, 12, 1.0),
                                                 (23, 25, 1.0),
                                                 (81, 83, 1.0),
                                                 (163, 165, 1.0)
                                                ]))
d['GPE'].append(dict(text = 'Brazil', offset = [(219, 221, 1.0),
                                                (260, 262, 1.0)
                                               ]))

d['CARDINAL'].append(dict(text = 'at least 3000', offset = [(26, 29, 1.0)]))
d['CARDINAL'].append(dict(text = '124', offset = [(94, 95, 1.0)]))
print(d)
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have added the code and intermediate results.

Comment: Added example using pandas groupby().

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
from collections import defaultdict
from pprint import pprint

el = [...same elements...]

d = defaultdict(list)
e = defaultdict(list)

for k, v in groupby(el, key=lambda x: x[0]):
    for x, y, *z in v:
        e[y].append(tuple(z))   
    
    for g, h in e.items():
        d[k].append((g, h))

    e = defaultdict(list)

g = dict(d)

print(g.items(),'\n')
pprint(g, width=100, sort_dicts=False)
```

```
dict_items([('GPE', [('Germany', [(10, 12, 1.0), (23, 25, 1.0), (81, 83, 1.0), (163, 165, 1.0)]), ('Brazil', [(219, 221, 1.0), (260, 262, 1.0)])]), ('CARDINAL', [('at least 3000', [(26, 29, 1.0)]), ('124', [(94, 95, 1.0)])])])

{'GPE': [('Germany', [(10, 12, 1.0), (23, 25, 1.0), (81, 83, 1.0), (163, 165, 1.0)]),
         ('Brazil', [(219, 221, 1.0), (260, 262, 1.0)])],
 'CARDINAL': [('at least 3000', [(26, 29, 1.0)]), ('124', [(94, 95, 1.0)])]}
```

Comment: This has answered the question.